# EMC VNXe3200 LUN cli command

Tags: emc

I'm using the below command to view the LUN configuration in VNXe1600.
**/stor/prov/luns/lun show -detail**.
 And i'm trying the same command in VNXe3200 but, nothing is display.
**/metrics/metric show** This command is used to list all performance command supported by VNXe.
Is there any Unisphere commands to list all configuration command supported by VNXe.

Thanks in advance.